# Cmd click on top of Xcode used to open a Finder - this no longer works in Yosemite

Tags: macos, xcode

I used to be able open a Finder window by Cmd clicking the title at the top of the Xcode window.

However, in Yosemite, with its new slimline display, the title is no longer shown.

Is there a fix or an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now crtl click on the Project container or a file inside to get to the Project folder or file.

[image]